# I hava a loop login because of problems with PATH environment

Tags: environment-variables

I can't login because of the loop. So I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, login and it shows:

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
* /bin/lesspipe
* /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in the following places
* /bin/dircolors
* /usr/bin/dircolors
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show? Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/environment`?